# Pytorch CNN: Expected input to have 1 channel but got 60000 channels instead

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network, mnist

While implementing a NN for Fashion MNIST dataset, I'm getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [6, 1, 5, 5], expected input[1, 60000, 28, 28] to have 1 channels, but got 60000 channels instead
```

I'm inferring that 60000 is the length of my entire dataset, but not sure why is the algorithm giving this error. Can someone help me fix this please?

My dataset:

```
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
train_data = []
test_data = []
train_data.append([X_train, y_train])
test_data.append([X_test, y_test])

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=100)
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data, shuffle=True, batch_size=100)
```

I'm getting the error in following order (as per stack trace):

```
      8     #making predictions
----> 9     y_pred = model(images)

     32     #first hidden layer
---> 33     x = self.conv1(x)
```

**Update 1**

Added the line:

```
images = images.transpose(0, 1)
```

to transpose the image as pointed out by Ivan but now getting the error:

```
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Byte but found Float
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You input is shaped `(1, 60000, 28, 28)`, while it should be shaped `(60000, 1, 28, 28)`. You can fix this by transposing the first two axes:

```
>>> x.transpose(0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, I added the statement right before calling the model function but got a new error. Please refer to my update.

Comment: This should be selected as the correct answer. The new error that you are getting is unrelated with the title.

Comment: @Ashar you will have to convert your input to float: `x.float()`.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you used TensorFlow's datasets. I've used torchvison's dataset and it works fine

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision.datasets import FashionMNIST
from torchvision import transforms


class Network(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Network,self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,out_channels=6,kernel_size=5)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=6,out_channels=12,kernel_size=5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=12*4*4,out_features=120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=120,out_features=60)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=60,out_features=40)
    self.out = nn.Linear(in_features=40,out_features=10)
  def forward(self,x):
    #input layer
    x = x
    #first hidden layer
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = F.max_pool2d(x,kernel_size=2,stride=2)
    #second hidden layer
    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    x = F.max_pool2d(x,kernel_size=2,stride=2)
    #third hidden layer
    x = x.reshape(-1,12*4*4)
    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    #fourth hidden layer
    x = self.fc2(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    #fifth hidden layer
    x = self.fc3(x)
    x = F.relu(x)
    #output layer
    x = self.out(x)
    return x


batch_size = 1000
train_dataset = FashionMNIST(
    '../data', train=True, download=True, 
    transform=transforms.ToTensor())
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

test_dataset = FashionMNIST(
    '../data', train=False, download=True, 
    transform=transforms.ToTensor())
testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

model = Network()

losses = []
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters())
epochs = 10

for i in range(epochs):
    batch_loss = []
    for j, (data, targets) in enumerate(trainloader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        ypred = model(data)
        loss = criterion(ypred, targets.reshape(-1))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        batch_loss.append(loss.item())
    if i>10: 
        optimizer.lr = 0.0005
    losses .append(sum(batch_loss) / len(batch_loss))
    print('Epoch {}:\tloss {:.4f}'.format(i, losses [-1]))
```